# C# transferring lots of small files over a network

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange, file-transfer

I have wrote a C# console application to copy lots of small XML files (about 80000 files, round about 300KB each, total size of about 3GB gets transferred) from a share directory on an AS400 Machine to a share directory on a windows Machine.

The two machine are on the same LAN, but it is taking many hours to do the copying.  I need to loop through the files, as I need to update a table in the DB, I know this could maybe the bottle neck, but excluding the SQL update; Is there a faster way to transfer these files?

```
    public void CopyFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo IFS = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\AS400Machine\ShareFolder\");

        string NewPath = @"\\WindowsMachine\ShareFolder\";

        Directory.CreateDirectory(NewPath);
        foreach (FileInfo xmlFile in IFS.GetFiles())
        {
            var newFullPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", NewPath, xmlFile.Name);

            // SQL Update

            // Copy File
            xmlFile.CopyTo(newFullPath, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried concatenating or compressing the files?

Comment: My suggestion is 1. combine files in chunks (i.e. 1000 files per chunk) 2. Pack chunk, then copy to destination folder and unpack it.

Comment: So requesting the files from the AS400 share to pull them into your C# code is already pretty slow I'd imagine. Have you discussed consolidating the xml files or zipping a number of them together with the AS400 guys?

Comment: 3Gb is 24,000Mbits @ 100Mbps that's 240 seconds. Even at 10Mbps it's only 40 minutes. If it's taking many hours then you might want to do some more research into where the bottle neck is. Also note that 300Kb * 80000 is 24GB

Comment: @ZioN did you perform any test to understand which of the step is the slowest?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Its an option I have been considering, but I think Serge  suggest to do it in chunk may improve preformance

Comment: @JamesBarrass, that is a good idea

Comment: Copying files generally gets *better* overall throughput for larger files and *worse* overall throughput for smaller files, since each file has to be opened on the sending end, created on the receiving end, etc. So the systems are spending more time opening and closing files than they would if you had one big file of the same overall size.

Comment: Have you considered writing this in an IBM i language to run there, copying the stream files to /QNTC?

Comment: @WarrenT that might be a good idea, not looking forward to the writing it in RPG, but something worth considering.

Comment: If you know C# then perhaps C/C++ might be worth considering, possibly under PASE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your program runs on *Machine C* and it transfers files from *Machine A* to *Machine B*, there's not much you can do here except doing the copying in multiple threads or processes.

If you could run your program on both machines, you could do some nifty tricks like zipping the files up so that you'd be transferring a single (or several) large files instead of thousand of small ones.

Comment: Yeah. Split, run multiple at the same time until the IO turns into a problem (which will happen sonner or later).

Comment: You have right picture what what is happening.  I have those 3 machines.  I do not think I can run a C# app on a AS400 though.

Answer (score 1):

Where are the files at on the AS/400?  If in the /QDLS file system, that could be much of your problem.

Also, if you're actually using an AS/400; as opposed to more modern hardware & OS.

Lastly, assuming you do have modern hardware, you might ask the IBM i folks to check the settings on the network card.  I've seen 10Mbit half duplex left over from original hardware configured on newer 1GBit hardware.

Comment: Many, many shops refer to their system(s) as AS/400, probably because that is the term they have used for years.  But they use the term even after it has been replaced several times with newer iSeries or Power Systems. Yet these same people wouldn't think of calling their desktop system a PC-XT.  Perhaps one reason is that they see the hardware change on their desk, but a server sitting somewhere unseen can change without being noticed much beyond improved response time.

Comment: @WarrenT again you sharing your you knowledge what the IBM Mid Range Machines real name is ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should get better performance if the files are stored as BLOBS in a DB2 table rather than stream files on the IFS.